# How to redirect all requests to index.php and keep the other GET params?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I've got so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

But when I go to soemthing like `/a?b=c` and then inspect the GET params, I only get `a` for `url`, and `b` is lost. How can I retain that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

You need the QSA in your rewrite rule.

Comment: This also redirects my CSS and JS files...I would like those to keep working and pointing to where they should.

Comment: @vsync Then add a `RewriteCond` which does not match those files. For example: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/` to not rewrite any files under the `js` directory.

Answer (score 25):

How about using the FallbackResource directive: "Define a default URL for requests that don't map to a file"

```
<Directory /web/example.com/htdocs/blog>
    FallbackResource /index.php
</Directory>
```

That way you don't have to call the modRewrite module on every request.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: How does one get this to work if your index is not at the root directory? E.g. I want mysite.com/project/* to fallback to mysite.com/project/index.php. I could do FallbackResource /project/index.php, but it would be nice to somehow have a path relative to the .htaccess where it's defined (That way I can move project dir to projectX dir without modifying .htaccess)

Comment: Isn't using the fallback actually slower than a direct redirect? Since the visitor now has to wait until the engine fails **all** matches before getting redirected to index.php.