# htaccess rewrite all subfolders (/../..) to index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a one page application. When the user changes the url, or reloads, anything after "mysite.com/" is sent as a variable to ajax the requested subdirectory content (e.g. /users/me)

This code works great when the relative url has only one "sub-directory".
But sub-sub-directories, and even simply "sub-directory/", receive errors and load no content.

- mysite.com/sub_directory -------------------------- navigates to mysite.com/index.html
- mysite.com/sub_directory/ ------------------------- throws error
- mysite.com/sub_directory/sub-sub-directory --- throws error

*Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mysite.com/all/default.css" 

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "mysite.com/all/jquery.js"*

htaccess attempt: redirect anything after "mysite.com/" to index.html.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Additional info: 
.* and (^/?.*$) and (^.*/$)* and .*/ etc. produce the same results 
including the AddType rules for .css and .js files seems to do nothing. 
The htaccess file sits in the same folder as index.html

Is this a regex problem? Usually when there is a problem with the htaccess code, the server responds with a 500 internal server error, but in this case no content is loaded and the above error is thrown.

UPDATE: I have a bunch of scripts that are in a "scripts" folder, which is on the same directory-level as index.html and .htaccess. They all load without error, perhaps the problem is that .htaccess is not applying to the files in its own directory-level?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214502/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-index-php-and-keep-the-other-get-params

Comment: hmm, adding QSA doesn't seem to have any affect

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Okay so I got it working. The client would hang because it could not find the jquery and css files I had referenced. I'm thinking what happened is when the server read and loaded the index.html, it hit the lines

```
<script src="default.css"></script> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

and since they were not hard references to their file locations, they were not found and htaccess rerouted the request back to index.html, which continues in a loop to infinitum causing the browser to hang.

simply changing all 'real' file references to non-relative links fixes the problem

e.g.

```
<script src="http://www.mysite.com/default.css"></script>
```

silly that that was the solution, but I guess problems can be hard because the answer is too simple to notice

Comment: If you leave out http: it will take the script with the current protocol, so either http or https. Eg <script src="//www.mysite.com/default.css"></script>