# Php - get path after php script

Tags: php, html, apache, path

I have search high and low for an answer to my question and I cannot find it. Basically what I want to do is get the path after a php script. ex. "http://www.example.com/index.php/arg1/arg2/arg3/etc/" and get arg1, arg2, arg3, etc in an array. How can I do this in php and once I do this will "http://www.example.com/arg1/arg2/arg3/etc" still return the same results. If not then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Look up `$_SERVER`, `PATH_INFO` and `explode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to get the answer, and a few others you will have in the future. Make a script, e.g. "test.php", and just put this one line in it:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Then browse to it with http://www.example.com/test.php/one/two/three/etc

Look through the `$_SERVER` values for the one that matches what you are after.

I see the answer you want in this case in $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]: "/one/two/three/etc"
Then use `explode` to turn it into an array:

```
print_r( explode('/',$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );
```

However sometimes `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is going to be the one you want, especially if using URL rewriting.

**UPDATE:**

Responding to comment, here is what I'd do:

```
$args = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($args[0] == 'index.php')array_shift($args);
```

Comment: Nice answer but before I accept it I need to know if it is possible to make http://www.example.org/arg1/arg2 act the same as http://www.example.org/index.php/arg1/arg2.

Comment: @john01dav So the same script can be used for either way of being called? Yes, use REQUEST_URI, explode out, then filter out "index.php" if it is there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: No, I mean actually making the script be loaded like that and not interpreted as a directory as it currently is.

Comment: @john01dav That is a distinctly different question. Short answer is it is done with Apache config. E.g. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214502/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-index-php-and-keep-the-other-get-params

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
$url ="http://www.example.com/index.php/arg1/arg2/arg3/etc/";


$array =  explode("/",parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
if (in_array('index.php', $array)) 
{
    unset($array[array_search('index.php',$array)]);
}


print_r(array_values(array_filter($array)));
```

Comment: I went to write something like this, then realized it will mess up this URL:   example.com/arg1/index.php/arg3/   I.e. when one of the arguments is the magic string "index.php". Of course, the OP cannot do what he wants to do if index.php could validly be the first argument!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `parse_url` and `parse_str`

```
$url =$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 $ParseUrl = parse_url($url);
 print_r($ParseUrl);

 $arr =  parse_str($ParseUrl['query']);

 print_r($arr);
```